# C# RX example to utilise max X connections for Observable stream

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need smth similar to BlockingCollection so i can setup X connections (which will consume that IEnum/Obs stream) and in way so that if any of item are complete, it will pick up the next item.

I have looked at Buffer example which will wait for all X items in the buffer to complete before it can move to next set. As some items might take longer then other to complete. I dont want to wait for 10th (if X=10) to finish before processing the next batch. I want to utilise all X connections at max capacity

Comment: Does something like this work for you? `source.Select(n => Observable.Start(() => Process(n))).Merge(X)`

Comment: Merge did work! can you reply as an answer and then I will mark it as resolved!! Tnx